# Why is there an aws command embedded in the EKS kube config file?

Tags: amazon-eks

I'm curious about something in the kube config file generated by the `aws eks update-kubeconfig` command.  At the bottom of the file, there is this construct:

```
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:redacted:cluster/u62d2e14b31f0270011485fd3
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - u62d2e14b31f0270011485fd3
      command: aws
```

It is clearly an invocation of the `aws eks get-token` command. Why is this here?  Does this command get automatically called?

Comment: FYI, the #kubernetes tag specifically says: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Why is this here?`

The command gets an IAM token using your IAM account and pass along to EKS via the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer <token>` for authentication. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-auth.html) for details.

`Does this command get automatically called?`

Yes, by `kubectl`.